# How do I update React component on a global variable change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I have a React component that shows details of a soccer game when that game is clicked on in a table, called `GameData`. The table is part of another component, and it updates a variable that `GameData` uses to show the data. That variable is global, so using `useState()` inside of `GameData` doesn't work. How do I make `GameData` re-render when the variable updates/changes?

Here is what my `GameData` component is currently:

```js
let gameToDisplay = {};

function displayGameData(gameId) {
    gameToDisplay = gameData.find(game => game.id === gameId);
    // This function runs when a game in the table is clicked. This part updates and works as expected. 
}

function GameData() {
    const [gdDisplay, setgdDisplay] = useState(true);

    function handleDetailClick() {
        setgdDisplay(!gdDisplay);
    }

    return (
        <div className='GameData box'>
            <h2>Game Details</h2>
            <div className='Links'>
                <ButtonGroup variant="contained" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
                    <Button onClick={handleDetailClick}>{gdDisplay ? 'Less' : 'More'} details</Button>
                </ButtonGroup>
            </div>
            {gdDisplay ? (
                <p className='data'>
// Data display that gets data from gameToDisplay 
                </p>
            ) : ( 
                <></> 
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Yes, the button approach works, but you have to click the button twice for the data to update. I'm trying to change the data inside of `<p className='data'>` when `gameToDisplay` is changed. How can I watch for that variable to change and re-render `<p className='data'>` when that happens?

Comment: You can't do this, somehow your react components need to be "connected" to changes to that variable. Usually this is done via a hook of some kind.  You seem to want to pass a global down the entire hierarchy of your components. You can read on [useContext](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext). I am not suggesting to actually use `useContext` but the usage scenarios contain useful information to help you determine whether context is the correct thing to use and what alternatives to consider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I update React component on a global variable change?

You don't.  Don't use global variables.  Use state.

State doesn't *have to be* local to this exact component.  If this component needs to be re-rendered based on a state change in another component, you have a variety of options:

- [Lift state up](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components) so that it's managed by a common parent component and passed to the child components as props.
- Use [the `useContext` hook](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext) to manage state outside of the components.
- Use [a custom hook](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks) which manages the state outside of the component(s) and provides access to reading and setting that state within any component which needs it.
- Use a "global" [state management system](https://redux.js.org/) which manages state outside of the components and allows components to subscribe to that state.

Basically, overall you're thinking about it the wrong way.  You're trying to use React *without using React* by managing "state" manually in your global variables and re-rendering components manually with your own logic.

Don't.

React manages state updates and component re-renders.  That's its core functionality.  So if your goal is to use React then, well, use React.

Comment: Thanks for the links! I'm brand new to React and didn't know much about that. I'll take a look and see if I can make it work with my current code.

Comment: It worked! I used your first link and moved both components inside of a common parent. Thank you for the help!